# How do I extract a NALU unit in objective c? I want to copy all the bytes following the code hex value 00000001 67

Tags: objective-c, h.264

I want to copy all the values between 00000001 67 to the next occurrence of   00000001 67.

Any help will be appreciated.

[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGvs.png)

Comment: 00 00 01 67 is the SPS. it’s possible there in only ever one of them in the entire video an there would never be a second occurrence.

Comment: there is a second occurrence of 0000001 67

Comment: In your specific video, sure. I’m not just it not required that the SPS is repeated. So whatever you are trying to do will not work for all videos.